# Creating a new session or user from a different view/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controllers

I am creating a Rails App (I'd like to know how to do this in Rails 3.1 and 3.0) on Mac OSX 10.6.

I am using a PagesController to handle mostly static pages but would like to include a signup form on the home page and a login option in a persistent, static top bar on each page generated from my PagesController (home, about, contact, help, etc.).

I am having a little bit of trouble getting forms to work when they are outside of a given controller -> view. For example, I have a SessionsController and then the view (new.html.erb) where I have a form that when submitted creates a new session for login purposes. However, I am looking to implement this same form/functionality outside of the SessionsController and on views belonging to the PagesController (ie home.html.erb or about.html.erb). I'd like to do the same with the signup functionality: I'd like to have a signup form at home.html.erb and not have to send people to the "new" page in the UsersController. It seems like a simple redirect action when the form is submitted but I am having trouble figuring this out. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be have the signup form (.erb) file as a partial and include it in both Users and Pages controllers.

By that way your registration form is portable to any controller. And when the form is posted after saving you could redirect the user to where the request came from.

Comment: What type of redirect command would I issue? For example, if someone signed up on the home page in from the PagesController, how would I make it so that the "home" action in the PagesController passes the information from the form to the proper action in the UsersController to create the new User?

Comment: The registration should always go directly to the users controller. You can handle redirection back after that.

Comment: I see, so how do I set it up so the registration goes directly to the UsersController to create the User when it is being handled by the PagesController in the separate view?

Comment: Have your registration form partial sends the data to UsersController to create the user, then after creating the user you can check from where the request came from. (probably using a hidden field) if the request came from the PagesController, you can redirect back the user for it.